# Xcode 9 - Test target X encountered an error (Unable to connect to Test Manager)

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing

I'm trying to run some of my Unit Tests but it kept giving me error:

```
Showing Recent Issues
Test target X encountered an error (Unable to connect to test manager on d7306c4130298fbc17bc0985ec02f808dcdc1374 If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the log file at /var/folders/2h/0y4yjs6s7l307mbr6pk1xdl00000gn/T/com.apple.dt.XCTest/IDETestRunSession-CF80FA05-C8ED-4FCE-A04B-4A8070F21059/X-E8F39B10-0CDC-43D5-9BED-CD2D0F6081DA/Session-X-2018-01-08_161733-D3YlRc.log)
```

I've tried searching for this type of error but to no avail. Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: Could you solve this problem?

Answer (score 25):

Simply restarting the device fixed this for me (iOS 11.3)

Answer (score 11):

I resolved this issue by doing a hard restart of my device. For my iPhone 8, I followed these instructions from macrumors.com: 
[Hard restart iPhone 8](https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/force-restart-or-hard-reset-iphone-8-and-8-plus/)

Alternatively, if you're an [libimobiledevice](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice) user you can use `/usr/local/bin/idevicediagnostics restart` from your mac's terminal.

Hope this helps

Comment: Should i connect my iPhone to run the unit test ? Or, is it just run the test without build app in any simulator or real device?

Comment: @calvinsugianto, you need either a real device or a simulator if your end target is an iPhone or iPad.

Answer (score 7):

I restarted my iPhone 6 (iOS 11.2.6) in a normal way to resolve the same issue.

Comment: Worked on a 5s as well (iOS 11.4.1).